# Filter millions of strings and keep only unique ones Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsset

I have a very large amount of strings in 200 txt files which I'm trying to filter and keep the unique ones only. I was thinking to use NSSet for this, but the problem is that there are 300 millions of string in initial files and I can't load them all into a NSSet because its initializing for a very long time.

Can anybody suggest a better approache or a work around that could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you forced to use text files for source data ?

Comment: Well I have all the strings in txt files so I guess yes.

Comment: But probably I can transfer them to a DB or something like this. But again this probably will take time.

Comment: what is the point of doing this on Objective-C ? Can't you do this in a language more suitable to this kind of thing like Python for example, then save the output and use it in your obj-c program ?

Comment: Of course you are right. But I started to do it in Objective-C and I was wandering if somebody can suggest me a good solution.

Comment: How long is "a very long time"? How many unique strings do you expect? How much memory is used? A good solution might be just to have a bit of patience.

Comment: Well I was able already to solve this problem and it took about one hour to filter 300 mlns of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution that is low cost for memory and cpu consumption :

You can use a sqlite database : create a table with one column string as unique key that will receive each string you are parsing.

During insertion of each string, if string is already in the table it won't be inserted and at the end the table will only contain unique strings.

Make your code in order to keep insertions of strings on insertion failure because of an already existing string (duplicate key)

Edit : add also an index on this column because your needs concerns a lot of entries

Comment: Actually this sounds really good. I will definetly give it a try. But wouldn't this take also a lot of time if lets say I add a new string in DB where there already are 100 mlns unique strings. But this still may be a good solution as I will be able to use the computer while program is running.

Comment: You can also add an index on this column for faster treatments on new insert when there are already a lot of entries.

With that many string to process in texts files, it will always take some time (it's not best conditions do deal with lots of strings)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just keep the unique ones in memory. As long as you parse the files you can compare each string readed with the ones that are in the unique array and if there are no match add it to the array. But maybe this is not a very good solution because if you have a lot of unique strings this could lead to many comparisons and this could take some time either. 

But give it a try, measure the time of execution and see if this work for your case.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not the case. Using NSSet I guess it also write unique ones in memory and then adds other strings if there are no match. I was trying this but program works for really long time as I think I have something like 150 mln unique strings.